# Why dont microwaves pass through the microwave door

Tags: optics, electromagnetic-radiation, microwaves

What is the classical explanation for why the microwaves won't pass through the microwave door?

I know the microwaves behave like particles and dont pass through the microwave door but I am asking why they do so.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How does the grid on the microwave oven window prevent microwave radiation from coming out?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/29357/)

Comment: In *classical* electromagnetism microwaves do *not* behave like particles. They are *waves*, as their name says.

Comment: and  as they are classical waves, the size of the holes on the metal of the door and the distance between them is such as to "break the waves" and reflect them back to the interior., which is the faraday cage referred in the duplicate. For the wavelength of the microwave waves, it is as if it is all metal.

Comment: Water waves would pass through an obstruction like that. Why don't electromagnetic waves?

Comment: water might pass,but if the same wave computations are done with respect to the water wave's wavelength, the water  wave would be reflected. Roughly: the oven microwave wavelenth is 24.24 cm, the gaps in the door 1mm. A water wavelength is of order of meters, would the water wave get through a wall with holes of half a mm?

Comment: please note that in order to get the attention of a commenter you should use @xxx(example  @annav.) I just happened to check and saw your question